# Performing query on two databases with stored procedure for returning two sets of data on dropdown

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two drop downs on a form. Second drop down populates based on value selected on the first drop down. One of two stored procedures query I have basically displays data where the value for @LocID does not match selected on first dropdown does not exist and also performs subquery where no zipcodes are returned for anything matched with the declared @LocID.

```
DECLARE @LocID INT;

SELECT
 DISTINCT l.[ZipCode],
 [Description] = l.ZipCode + ' - ' + l.Description
FROM LocMap l
  WHERE l.ZipCode NOT IN (
  SELECT l2.ZipCode
  FROM LocMap l2
  WHERE l2.LocID = @LocID
);
```

Table named LocMap.

```
LocID | ZipCode | Description
----------------------------------
100  | 91012   | Magical Sky
100  | 91013   | Dream Land
101  | 91012   | Blue Ocean
102  | 91012   | Gray Screen
104  | 91014   | Limit Break
108  | 91016   | Magic Hammer
```

My problem is my second stored procedure that also returns data to this second dropdown labeled as Recently Added. It basically queries a table and returns all data for it (ZipCode + Description), no criteria or anything. What I would like to know is if it is possible to query two databases on the same server and if so, how exactly I would perform the same filtering of data I am doing on my stored procedure above with the stored procedure query for this second table. The first stored procedure has the @declare LocID, but this second one, all it does is return everything without anything being declared.

1) What would be the recommended way of doing this. Is it possible to get the results from first stored procedure and do a subquery similar to filter out my data with RecentlyAdded? Just like the first query, I don't want to return any zipcodes that match the LocID passed on this second table result as well.

Second stored procedure table named RecentlyAdded

```
ZipCode | Description
----------------------------------
91018   | Zelda
91019   | Sephiroth
91012   | Cloud
91012   | Aeris
91011   | Tifa
91010   | Barrett

Dropdown Layout Example

[Select LocID] (First Dropdown)
   100
   104
   108
   120

[Select ZipCode - Description] (Second Dropdown]
  ---Recently Added---
    91010 - Barrett
    91018 - Zelda
    ......................
    ......................
    ......................
  ---All other ZipCodes---
    91016 - Magic Hammer
    91014 - Limit Break
    ......................
    ......................
    ......................
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one fell swoop using the [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) operator:

```
DECLARE @LocID INT;

SELECT DISTINCT
    f.[ZipCode],
    [Description] = f.ZipCode + ' - ' + f.Description,
    f.[RecentlyAdded]
FROM (
    SELECT
        l.[ZipCode],
        l.[Description],
        RecentlyAdded = CAST(0 AS BIT)
    FROM LocMap l
    UNION
    SELECT
        r.[ZipCode],
        r.[Description],
        RecentlyAdded = CAST(1 AS BIT)
    FROM RecentlyAdded r
) f
WHERE f.ZipCode NOT IN (
    SELECT l2.ZipCode
    FROM LocMap l2
    WHERE l2.LocID = @LocID
)
ORDER BY RecentlyAdded DESC;
```

After you get the input from both tables, you can store the result as its own "table" and do the filtering / selecting as if you were only querying the one table.

Make sure you change the database / schema name for RecentlyAdded above appropriately (didn't see it in the post).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e4a65/7)

Comment: I'm reading about UNION and it looks like it will do exactly what I need. However, I think I need to use just UNION instead of UNION ALL, since I don't need duplicate results included in my final result. Regarding storing result in own table, do you mean its creating a "virtual" or temporary table of some sort to do the final query or do I need to actually create a new table to store this information? Would it be better if I created a VIEW with the two tables from both databases combined, then use stored procedure to just perform query in my first post to view Table instead of DB?

Comment: It would depend on if you wanted items that were both RecentlyAdded to potentially show in both the top and bottom section of the dropdown - UNION would definitely be more appropriate if not.  As for the table, the execution engine handles all of this - you don't need to create a temp table / table variable to store it.  Creating a view would be a good idea if you were planning on using this somewhere else.

Comment: Hmmm, trying to see what I am doing wrong then. The line where you have "final f" says syntax error. Should I be adding a database schema to this?

Comment: Also, the column names for the recentlyadded table are different, even though the values correlate with zip code and description. Not so smart move on whoever created this originally. I'll double check to make sure I have references correct on my end.

Comment: Removed the "final" from the definition above - this should work now.  The only thing you should have to change is the name of the columns on RecentlyAdded - as long as the datatypes are compatible it should be fine.  You will have to cast them otherwise so that it works properly.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hey @bman2013 - did this work for you?  Let me know if it didn't and we can jump in chat and work through it.

Comment: Jordan, it did work for me. Thanks so much for your help in both questions. You are seriously a lifesaver and it really did open my eyes a lot more with writing SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use a temporary table to store the intermediate values as shown here. Depending on circumstances, either a true tamp table (as shown) or a table-valued variable might be appropriate.

```
create table #t(
    ZipCode  varchar(7)
    ,Description varchar(255)
);
-- N.B. Don't insert a **go** here

insert #t (ZipCode,Description)
exec <second stored procedure name and parameters>;

-- proceed to join to your prior query
```

Comment: About 4500 total results from table in DB, so probably better if I go with the TEMP table route instead of Table Variable just to future proof, although no complex data types, no max being used. I will give this a try.

Comment: I'm liking this more and more, however somewhat worried if this will create any issues with SQL server performance. (Not a high traffic server whatsoever). Is it necessary to add a DROP temporary table after my JOIN query if a TEMP table is supposed to be deallocated after the stored procedure session ends anyway?

Comment: @bman2013: You only need to DROP temporary tables beginning with ## (Global Temporary tables). Those with only a single hash are automatically dropped when they go out of scope. (When the connection is released, if memory serves.) However, as a matter of sound programming practice I try to always drop them once o longer needed.  I have found temporary tables to increase performance in general, not degrade it, but this can depend on precise circumstances. However, deal with specific performance problems as they occur rather than with all possible problems you can think of. ...

Comment: @bman2013: Simply design soundly and few performance problems will arise.